# What are Java Programmers called?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I know that those who code in Python could be called Pythonistas, Pythoneers and Pythonists and Ruby programmers could be called Rubyists.

Anyways, my question is, are there nicknames for other language users? More specifically, is there one for a person that codes Java?

Comment: Those are all made up words, so just make up another word.

Comment: *Starbuckers*? *Javanistas*? Or simply *Joes*?

Comment: _Javahuts, javajava, javajive, javalines, javalinos, javouzem._

Comment: Java and C# (and C/C++) programmers are the mainstream. Normally, only the non-mainstream needs to be given special honour to have special names to distinguish themselves despite their esoteric and low functionality and over-worshipped languages.

Comment: If I had a vote (which I don't), I'd call them _Javamanos_, after _Java_ + _manos_ [hands]. And you could urge them on to higher achievement by shouting "Javamanos muchachos!"

Comment: Perhaps ***verbosers***?

Comment: "VBidiot" - noun. Stubborn programmer who refuses to give up on VB6. See also, ckuhn203.

Comment: @SvenYargs Is the similarity to a washbasin incidental or intentional?

Comment: After another round of layoffs, Barristas!

Comment: Garbage collectors?

Comment: What about Javavore ?

Comment: They're called *brilliant*!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a former employee of Sun Microsystems, I think I can explain why there is no single word for Java programmers.  To preserve its trademark, Sun had a policy of discouraging any creative modification of the word "Java".  For example, the use of the once-current word "Javatized" to mean "implemented in Java" was suppressed, with "Java-enhanced" as the recommended wording.

Courts have taken the coinage of related words as evidence of [trademark erosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark#Avoiding_genericization), which would lead to "Java" being reclassified as a generic trademark.

Comment: Nice answer. I'm not convinced that this is *the* answer (because I agree with the gist of @BlessedGeek's comment), but it's definitely a worthwhile, interesting, and enlightening answer. And for all I know, it *could* be the "correct" answer.

Answer (score -1):

I have not come across a name for Java programmers but since Java used to be called OAK you could possibly make your own name up for them, like OAKies and then put a footnote on the page you are first using it on, Might have to do some research on other previous names for Java